# Accessing functionality from parent component in child component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have working code in `App.jsx`. Everything is working when this written together in one file.

```
const App = props => {
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(getProducts());

  //const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState();

  const handleAddProductToCart = productID => {
    setCartProducts([...cartProducts, productID]);
  };
  const handleRemoveFromCart = productID => {
    const newCartProducts = cartProducts.filter(id => id !== productID);
    setCartProducts(newCartProducts);
  };

  /*const filterItems = ({ description, title }) => {
    return title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
      || description.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
  }*/

  return (
    <>
    <Header/>
    <Search/>
    <Sidebar/>
    <div>
      {products.map(product => {
        const { id, title, description, image } = product;
        let haveInCart = false;

        cartProducts.forEach(productID => {
          if (productID === id) {
            haveInCart = true;
          }
        });

        return (
          <Card key={id} className="item-card">
            <CardImg src={image} alt={title} className="item-img" style={{ height: '260px' }} />
            <CardBody style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-body">
              <CardTitle style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-title">{title}</CardTitle>
              <CardText style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-text">{description}</CardText>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartPlus} className="add-icon" onClick={() => handleAddProductToCart(id)} />
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
      <h2>Your Cart</h2>
      {cartProducts.length > 0
        ? cartProducts.map(productID => {
          const productIndex = products.findIndex(product => {
            return product.id === productID;
          });
          let { id, title, image } = products[productIndex];
          return (
            <Card key={id} className="item-card">
              <CardImg src={image} alt={title} className="item-img" style={{ height: '260px' }} />
              <CardBody style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-body">
                <CardTitle style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-title">{title}</CardTitle>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className="remove-icon" onClick={() => handleRemoveFromCart(id)} />
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          );
        })
        : "Yor Cart is Empty :("}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I want to put product Card and cart Card into it's own component. And when I'm doing it, like this

```
const Product = ({product}) => {
    const { id, title, description, image } = product;
    return (
        <Card key={id} className="item-card">
            <CardImg src={image} alt={title} className="item-img" style={{ height: '260px' }} />
            <CardBody style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-body">
                <CardTitle style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-title">{title}</CardTitle>
                <CardText style={{ border: 'none' }} className="custom-card-text">{description}</CardText>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartPlus} className="add-icon" /*onClick={() => handleAddProductToCart(id)}*/ />
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

I'm not getting properties of product in my Card. I want to make my code better organized and save it's functionality. How to access those states from `Product` and `Cart` component?

**EDIT**
Here's the link to codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cookies-r2inh?file=/src/App.jsx&fbclid=IwAR38tcE39tVL51YpG4_6A1HRz-kth1GSIocQWMPrU3QXepc5CHUNn-ZqiG8

**EDIT 2** How I can make items in cart be displaying beside `Product` component, on the left side? Should I create entire Cart component for it?

Comment: How does your code look after refactoring? Could you prepare a code sandbox example?

Comment: @slaid3r added sandbox

Comment: @Ati How did you call your Product card in your App ? Have you pass product to your Product card ?

Comment: Yeah, `<Product product={product} />`. But function `handleAddProductToCart` isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Product.jsx file should look like this:

```
import React from "react";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCartPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import CardBody from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import CardImg from "react-bootstrap/CardImg";
import CardTitle from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import CardText from "react-bootstrap/Card";

const Product = ({ product, handleAddProductToCart }) => {
  const { id, title, description, image } = product;
  return (
    <Card key={id} className="item-card">
      <CardImg
        src={image}
        alt={title}
        className="item-img"
        style={{ height: "260px" }}
      />
      <CardBody style={{ border: "none" }} className="custom-card-body">
        <CardTitle style={{ border: "none" }} className="custom-card-title">
          {title}
        </CardTitle>
        <CardText style={{ border: "none" }} className="custom-card-text">
          {description}
        </CardText>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faCartPlus}
          className="add-icon"
          onClick={() => handleAddProductToCart(id)}
        />
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

And in your App.jsx you can map the products array like this:

```
    {products.map((product) => (
      <Product
        product={product}
        key={product.id}
        handleAddProductToCart={handleAddProductToCart}
      />
    ))}
```

EDIT:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-swartz-5q2fo
I edited the codesandbox, i made the Product component accept both add and remove product callback and the "haveInCart" prop. It will decide which icon and which callback to use base on that prop. I'm not sure about this approch tho

Comment: No need to pass the id. You can pass entire a "() => handleAddProductToCart(id)"  as  handleAddProductToCart props

Comment: @Syder ok, how to be with product, which is added to cart? it's the same product card but with delete icon?

Comment: oh, i see what you're trying to do, give me a minute and i'll fix it

Comment: Here's an updated sandbox -  https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cookies-89-891d5, you might fork it and add it to the response.

Comment: Try to think of the composition model of ReactJS. Don't pack everything in the same component. An icon can be an individual dumb component, which takes just one prop. That one prop will be in the form of a function which when executed from the Icon will call the main logic function in the uppermost parent component.

@ati